# Compare DateTime with 24 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net

``I have a method to retrieve DateTime from MS Acesss. I want to allow a client to cancel his booking up to 24 hours prior to the date. How can I code this using if else statement?

this is my method.

```
    public static string Date(int c)
    {
        string a;
        OleDbConnection myconn = DBConn();
        string myQ = "SELECT DateTime FROM Booking WHERE movie_ID=" + c;
        OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand(myQ, myconn);
        try
        {
            myconn.Open();

            a = myCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


            return a;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myconn.Close();
        }
    }
```

How to code if else statement like
       string d = db.date(id);
       DateTime n = Convert.toDateTime(d);
       if ( n <= 24 hours???){
       do.this....
      }

Comment: share code what have you already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a method like this

```
public static bool canCancel(string date)
{
    DateTime booking = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
    DateTime ending = booking.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);

    var n = DateTime.Compare(ending, DateTime.Now);
    if(n == -1)
    {
       // within 24 hour from booking
       // so can not cancel
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
       // greater than 24 hour
       // so can cancel
       return true;
    }


}
```

then call it

```
public static string Date(int c)
    {
        string a;
        OleDbConnection myconn = DBConn();
        string myQ = "SELECT DateTime FROM Booking WHERE movie_ID=" + c;
        OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand(myQ, myconn);
        try
        {
            myconn.Open();

            a = myCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            var can_cancel = canCancel(a);
            return a;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myconn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry for late reply. I want to allow client to cancel booking is the time is more than 24 hours. If less than 24 hours, I don't to allow them to cancel the booking. Looks like your code got it the other way

Comment: Thank you. Your idea did worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you function as per your requirements but hope below gives you an idea:

```
try
    {
        myconn.Open();
        a = myCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        DateTime DateFromAccess = Convert.ToDateTime(a);

       TimeSpan difference = DateFromAccess.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
       if (difference.TotalHours > 24)
          //Your Code to Cancel Booking
       else
          //"Booking can not be cancelled now";

        return a;
    }

catch(Exception){
    //Handle exception
}
```